# Why can't I assign null to an Object in C#?

Tags: c#, events, object, radio-button

I am trying to write a code in C# using event between to WinForms. I would like to change color text in a RichTextBox of the 1. form and the 2. form using RadioButton (RadioButtons are on the 2. form), but when i declare the variable: `Color valgtFarge = null;` I get this error message: `Cannot convert null to 'System.Drawing.Color' because it is a non-nullable value type`. What am I doing wrong?
The function:

```
private void rtf2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color colorChoice = null;

    if (rbtnBlack.Checked)
        colorChoice = Color.Black;

    //same here for the others RadioButtons

    if (myEventHandler != null && rtf2.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        myEventHandler(this, new Form1EventArgs(rtf2.Text.Substring(rtf2.Text.Length - 1),
            colorChoice));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color` is a struct, not a class. Structs cannot be `null`. If you want a nullable struct, you can use `Nullable<Color>` (or its shorthand syntax `Color?`) for your type instead.

Reading material: [Classes and Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Well because `Color` is a `struct`, and structs can't be *null*. You can use `Nullable<T>` to make it nullable:

```
Nullable<Color> colorChoice = null;
// or shorter
Color? colorChoice = null;
```

Then to get a value of a `Nullable` object, you use `Value` property or `GetValueOrDefault` method (you should prefer this if you don't know whether if it's *null* or not. Because the `Value` will throw an exception if it's *null*).For further reference:

- [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use  `Color.Empty;` which is similar to null but more safe.

```
Color color = Color.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as nullable with a question mark:

```
Color? color = null;
```